# Volume of a spherical box without integral.

Tags: geometry

A spherical box is the solid defined by $\rho_0\le \rho \le \rho_1,\ \theta_0\le \theta \le \theta_1,\ \phi_0\le \phi\le \phi_1$ in spherical coordinates. It looks like

[image]

Picture credit: KhanAcademy.

Is there an elementary way to compute the volume of this spherical box? When I used integrals, I have found that the volume is

$$\frac13 (\rho_1^3-\rho_0^3)(\theta_1-\theta_0)(\cos(\phi_1)-\cos(\phi_0)).$$

Comment: Think of ways to cut it out of one sphere. You can translate every cut into a mathematical formula. Like: Cutting a sphere by a plane through its center leads to $\frac 12 \cdot \frac 43 πr^3 = \frac 23πr^3$

Comment: Actually from the image I cannot verify that your formula is correct, as you don't show how you cut out the sphere exactly.

Comment: Assuming we already know the volume of the sphere is $4 \pi R^3/3$, it's sufficient to show that  volume of the spherical cone $0 < r < R$ and $0 < \theta < \theta_0$ is $(2\pi R^3/3)(1-\cos\theta_0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\phi$ to be the polar angle, a constant value of it corresponds
to a circular cone with apex at the origin, which intercepts a spherical cap of surface area
$$
A\left( {r,\phi } \right) = 2\pi r^{\,2} \left( {1 - \cos \phi } \right)
$$
which gives a ratio wrt the total surface of the sphere of
$$
\omega \left( \phi  \right) = {{A\left( {r,\phi } \right)} \over {4\pi r^{\,2} }} = {1 \over 2}\left( {1 - \cos \phi } \right)
$$
and the ratio comprised between $\phi_0$ and $\phi_1$ will be
$$
\omega \left( {\phi _{\,0} ,\phi _{\,1} } \right) =  - {1 \over 2}\left( {\cos \phi _{\,1}  - \cos \phi _{\,0} } \right)
$$

The dihedral angle $\theta_1 - \theta_0$ will then clearly intercept the fraction
$$
\omega \left( {\phi _{\,0} ,\phi _{\,1} ,\theta _{\,0} ,\theta _{\,1} } \right) = {{\left( {\theta _{\,1}  - \theta _{\,0} } \right)} \over {2\pi }}\omega \left( {\phi _{\,0} ,\phi _{\,1} } \right)
 =  - {{\left( {\theta _{\,1}  - \theta _{\,0} } \right)} \over {4\pi }}\left( {\cos \phi _{\,1}  - \cos \phi _{\,0} } \right)
$$
which in turn corresponds to the fraction of the volume intercepted between the two spheres
$$
\eqalign{
  & V = \omega \left( {\phi _{\,0} ,\phi _{\,1} ,\theta _{\,0} ,\theta _{\,1} } \right){{4\pi } \over 3}\left( {R^{\,3}  - r^{\,3} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  =  - \left( {R^{\,3}  - r^{\,3} } \right){1 \over 3}\left( {\theta _{\,1}  - \theta _{\,0} } \right)\left( {\cos \phi _{\,1}  - \cos \phi _{\,0} } \right) \cr} 
$$